# How can I make a local printer available over the network via internet printing protocol?

Tags: networking, drivers, printer, printing, webserver

So I have an old Canon printer and a Chromebook I want to be able to print from, The Canon printer has network functionality but does not show up to the Chromebook due to lack of drivers and IPP support. I figured I could just set up an IPP print server using Windows but have thus far been unable to. The idea being I send the print via ipp to the server and windows then forwards the print to the printer driver.

This would also allow me to print from other devices and operating systems like my phone or linux without installing drivers (which are not available). I believe this should be possible as Microsoft has documentation for server 2003 on how to do this but it does not match up with modern versions of Windows.

So far I have tried to get this working on Windows 10 and server 2019 by installing IIS (Internet Information Services) and IPP print services from "turn windows features on and off" and "server manager" and from what information I have found all you have to do is add and share a printer like you would normally and it should be avalible via IPP, Although it gets added under to the website "server ip/printers" and a address under properties is shown for the printer It is not a valid IPP address and only seems to work in windows which then causes the driver to be pulled and installed from the server.

Comment: does not show up to the Chromebook due to lack of drivers and IPP support.    ..........   So you will need to add a driver to the Chromebook if you can find one.  Otherwise not luck for the Chromebook.

Comment: Remember that driverless printing is a name but it is also a stretch of the imagination.  There needs to be a driver or IPP to do the work

Comment: To get it to work from Windows you need a driver. What is the printer model?

Comment: Can you see the printer device on the network, perhaps not recognized as a printer?